# Mathematica linear model fit to all data

Tags: fitting, dataset

I tried to use `LinearModelFit[data, x, x]` to fit linear curve to all data but I get an error:
[image]

The data looks like this:

[image]

Here is the file with data:[data](https://pastebin.com/nBfKG6HP)

Comment: I think you'll not get many people trying to download a "data" ???? file. Link doesn't work anyway.

Comment: If the data fits in the question, then please paste it in there. If it's too big, then please use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to share it.

Comment: The messages suggest that you need to `Clear[x]`.

Comment: Your figure suggests that there is a great amount of serial autocorrelation which is not accounted for in `LinearModelFit`.  The effect is that while the estimates of the slope and intercept might be fine, the associated standard errors will likely be too optimistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have some lingering definitions. Try `ClearAll[x]` before your code. Otherwise your approach works.

Let's make some data that looks like yours:

```
SeedRandom[2022]
data = Table[
         {x, -(x - 0.5) - 0.2 + 1/30 RandomReal[]}, 
         {x, 0.5, 1, 0.005}
       ];
ListPlot[data]
```

[image: ListPlot from fake data]

Then let's fit it using the same code you used:

```
LinearModelFit[data, x, x]
```

[image: picture of the resulting fitted model object]